# Laravel query on exact minute

Tags: php, laravel

I know I can run this query:

```
$five_minutes_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5);
$models = Model::whereBetween('created_at', $five_minutes_ago->startOfMinute(), $five_minutes_ago->endOfMinute())->get();
```

Is there a better way of writing this without using the `between`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```php
$five_minutes_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->format('Y-m-d h:i');

$models = Model::whereRaw("to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = ?", [$five_minutes_ago])->get();
```